# UniVerse learning materials

Tags: u2, universe, manuals, multivalue-database

I've recently come in contact with a proprietary descendant of UniVerse. Does anyone know where I can get a good tutorial or brush up on the syntactic quirks of its more popular parent? I can't figure out how to even get a table listing. Navigating my way around is difficult, and I don't see any man pages.

## UPDATED with the official Rocket Software links:

Special attention needs to be given to *`SQL Reference`*, *`SQL Administration for DBAs`*, and *`User Reference`*. There is also a link at the bottom of both of these pages to a zip with all of the docs. There is also a demo on Rocket Software (personal information required) for Universe 10.3, but it only works with RHEL. And, even though it is statically linked it segfaults for me using Ubuntu 8.10.

These links are official from Rocket Software (current owner of Uni* line of products)

- [UniVerse 10.3 Demo *latest*](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/downloads/UVPE_RHLINUX_10.3.3.zip)

  - [Guide to installing it on Ubuntu 9.10](https://serverfault.com/questions/103975/how-do-i-install-u2-universe-on-ubuntu-or-debian)
- [UniVerse 10.3 Documentation *latest*](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/pubs/library/103univ/)
- [Supporting whitepapers and theory](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/pubs/whitepapers.html)
- [Manual index page Servers & Tools](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/pubs/library/)

Here is one that predates Rocket Software's aquisition of the product line:

- [Old IBM ftp repository of U2 stuff](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/u2/)
- [IBM ZIP of 10.1 Documentation](http://www.elink.ibmlink.ibm.com/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=G251-2454-20#)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you're logged in...

**WHO** will tell you where you are.
**LISTF** will tell you the files/tables available.
**LIST *filename*** will get you at least the keys.
**LIST DICT *filename*** will give you some metadata.
**HELP** will give you some general info.
**HELP LIST** might get you on your way.

Brian Leach, a UniVerse Consultant in the UK, has some [excellent self-paced learning material](http://www.brianleach.co.uk/pages/books.htm)

The [U2-Users mailing list](http://109.104.64.69/cms/cmsview.wsp?id=newslist) has a tremendous depth of knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I like your quick rundown, it could have been slightly more detailed; but, I'm on my way to learning UniVerse.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of places to start:

[Jonathan E. Sisk - Pick/Basic](http://www.jes.com/pb/)
[Manny Neira and the Universe](http://www.mannyneira.com/universe/)
[U2 User Groups](http://old.nabble.com/U2---Users-f801.html)

Comment: +1 Manny Neira kept me sane during my first day on U2